# Award bounty points when I blew up the original question?

Tags: discussion, reputation, answers, bounties

I posted this SO question: [SQL write to ASP.NET user table doesn't save](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36611725/sql-write-to-asp-net-user-table-doesnt-save)

I put a bounty on the question and got some very reasonable suggestions, though nothing that led to an actual solution to my problem. (It's been a fairly painful week.)

I "solved" my own problem with a fairly significant architectural change to the way I'm storing user data. It's not a solution to the original problem; it's totally changing what the problem was. Feel free to read the thread for the gory details.

What's the etiquette regarding the outstanding bounty points? Should I let them expire? Award them to the highest voted answer? Give them to the one that caused me to think about how to re-attack my problem in a different way - but didn't provide details of the eventual answer?

Haven't found a meta thread that deals with this specific philosophical dilemma...

Comment: I would say if none helped you, then award it none, but submit an answer that outlines what you did since that was the solution you used

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should:

> Give them to the one that caused [you] to think about how to re-attack [your]
>   problem in a different way

Every answerer will have put effort into providing you with an answer so I think that effort should be rewarded if you can.

Just like users are encouraged to accept answers that helped them the most, I think it makes sense to award bounties to answers that helped them the most too.